# How to take data from database and store it in session PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session

i want to make TOEFL test. when user want to start the test, first user must input email. So, when user click start, user have an id. I want take id from table 'id' and save it in session. so when i want to take score from 'listening', 'structure' and 'reading' table, i used that id.

**but the problem is: when i do the test, listening, reading and structure score will be '0'. but i sure i has answered the questions correctly. Maybe it because id not save in session correctly.** please help meeee

index.php

```
<form method="POST" action="add_id.php">
         <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
         <input name="btn" type="submit" value="Start"/>
         </form>
```

add_id.php

```
<?php 
    include "connection.php";
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO id(email) VALUES ('$email')";
        if(mysql_query($query)){
         $q = "SELECT * FROM id";
         $ex=mysql_query($q);
         $id = $ex['id'];
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

        header("location:test_structure.php");
        }

        else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

calculate.php

```
<?
include "connection.php";
$id   =$_SESSION['id'];

              $query ="SELECT * FROM Reading WHERE Reading.id='$id'";
              $ex=mysql_query($query);
              $data=mysql_fetch_array($ex);
              $right_structure = $data['rightanswer_read'];
              $Reading = $data['score_read'];

              $query ="SELECT * FROM Structure WHERE Structure.id='$id'";
              $ex=mysql_query($query);
              $data=mysql_fetch_array($ex);
              $right_structure = $data['rightanswer_struct'];
              $Structure = $data['score_struct'];

              $q ="SELECT * FROM Listening WHERE Listening.id='$id'";
              $e=mysql_query($q);
              $d=mysql_fetch_array($e);
              $right_listening = $d['rightanswer_list'];
              $Listening = $d['score_list'];

              $final_score = (($Listening + $Structure + $Reading)/3) * 10; 

              $NA = "INSERT INTO final_score VALUES ('$email', '$final_score', '$Listening', '$Structure', '$Reading', '$right_listening', '$right_structure', '$right_reading')";
              if(mysql_query($NA)){
                   header("location:index.php");
              }else {
                    echo mysql_error();
              }

              }
              ?>
```

this is `id` table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `id` (
`id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: You must place `session_start();` at the top of every PHP page you wish  use session variables.

Comment: Since you are learning you should start out the right way. Don't use `mysql_` functions use either `mysqli` or `pdo`. Also don't put user input directly in your query, use parameterized queries with one of the two previously mentioned drivers.

Comment: @chris85 maybe we should be advising to steer clear of mysqli too (in favour of biting the bullet and getting immersed in PDO). Better to be set on as close to the right path from the start as possible would you agree?

Comment: @Jonathan Yea, but I'd prefer just to see `mysql_` be gone. On to parameterized queries everywhere..

Answer (score 0):

Change your `add_id.php` file like this,

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "connection.php";
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO id(email) VALUES ('$email')";
    if(mysql_query($query)){
         $id = mysql_insert_id();
         $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

        header("location:test_structure.php");
    }
    else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

Also read about function `mysql_insert_id()` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php